# ActivityRecognitionAPI keeps sending pending intents to the service

Tags: android, activity-recognition

I am using [ActivityRecognitionAPI](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi) in Android 4.4.2 to detect activities on the phone. I am using [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/ActivityRecognition) code to implement this.

The code requests for activity updates after every 15 seconds (I know, the documentation says that this is the upper bound but I have only this app on my device which requests this information) but the app keeps sending intents after every 3-4 seconds. I was thinking to save some battery based on activity but I guess, it would be draining more of it. Any suggestions for improvement?

Trimmed version of logs:

```
06-01 19:58:19.774:  Still 100%
06-01 19:58:23.414:  ACCCCCCCCCCTOVOTTTTTTESSS detected
06-01 19:58:27.104:  ACCCCCCCCCCTOVOTTTTTTESSS detected
06-01 19:58:27.104:  Still 100%
06-01 19:58:30.744:  ACCCCCCCCCCTOVOTTTTTTESSS detected
06-01 19:58:30.744:  Still 100%
06-01 19:58:34.424:  ACCCCCCCCCCTOVOTTTTTTESSS detected
06-01 19:58:34.424:  Still 100%
06-01 19:58:38.064:  ACCCCCCCCCCTOVOTTTTTTESSS detected
06-01 19:58:38.064:  Still 100%
06-01 19:58:41.684:  ACCCCCCCCCCTOVOTTTTTTESSS detected
06-01 19:58:41.684:  Still 100%
06-01 19:58:46.544:  ACCCCCCCCCCTOVOTTTTTTESSS detected
06-01 19:58:46.544:  Still 100%
06-01 19:58:50.224:  ACCCCCCCCCCTOVOTTTTTTESSS detected
06-01 19:58:50.224:  Still 100%
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation:

> Activities may be received more frequently than the detectionIntervalMillis parameter if another application has also requested activity updates at a faster rate. It may also receive updates faster when the activity detection service receives a signal that the current activity may change, such as if the device has been still for a long period of time and is then unplugged from a phone charger.

So the update detectionIntervalMillis parameter is more of a guideline.